# How to minify multiple JavaScript files using WebCompiler in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, bundling-and-minification, web-compiler

I'm using [Web Compiler](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler) for Visual Studio 2017. Compiling a single file is easy since the help is right there.

However, I want to minify multiple JavaScript files in my project, and I can't find how. Here's the list of the files I have:

```
/scripts/framework.js
/scripts/validation.js
/scripts/normalization.js
/scripts/shim.js
…
```

What I want to do is to bundle and minify all of these files into one single JavaScript file:

```
/scripts/all.js
```

How can I do that using Web Compiler?